# What is the explanation for the energy momentum tensor for incoherent dust?

Tags: relativity, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

I've read about the energy momentum tensor for incoherent dust in several sources such as [this page](http://ion.uwinnipeg.ca/~vincent/4500.6-001/Cosmology/EnergyMomentum_Tensors.htm) and Einstein's own book "The Meaning or Relativity". They say something like:

> The simplest energy-momentum tensor that can be constructed from these two dust quantities (the momentum $\rho$ and vector $v$) is the following: $T^{ab} = \rho v^a v^b$

I don't understand the physical justification for multiplying $v$ by itself to form a two dimensional energy-momentum tensor. I've read the [derivation here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/100072/energy-momentum-tensor-for-dust) but it is far from simple. Can someone provide an explanation?

Answer (score 3):

It might be helpful to start with non relativistic hydrodynamics and ask for the change of the momentum of a fluid in time. Let $\rho$ be the mass density of an incompressible fluid. If $\rho v$ is the momentum per volume, then we can write:
$$\frac{\partial(\rho v)}{\partial t}=\rho \frac{\partial v}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} v.$$
The first term on the right hand side can be processed by the Euler equation: 
$$\frac{\partial v^i}{\partial t}=-v^k \frac{\partial v^i}{\partial x^k}-\frac{1}{\rho}\frac{\partial p}{\partial x^i}$$
while $p$ is the pressure. The second term in the first equation can be replaced by the continuity equation:
$$\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}=-\frac{\partial (\rho v^k)}{\partial x^k}.$$
Then, after substitution of both and a few algebraic manipulations, we get:
$$\frac{\partial(\rho v^i)}{\partial t}=-\frac{\partial p}{\partial x^i}-\rho\,  v^k\frac{\partial v^i}{\partial x^k}-v^i\frac{\partial(\rho v^k)}{\partial x^k}.$$
Now, after applying the product rule on the right hand side we obtain the quadratic term of the velocity:
$$\frac{\partial(\rho v^i)}{\partial t}=-\frac{\partial p}{\partial x^i}-  \frac{\partial }{\partial x^k}(\rho\,v^iv^k).$$
The first term on the right hand side can be expressed with help of the Kronecker delta, i.e.:
$$\frac{\partial(\rho v^i)}{\partial t}=-\frac{\partial }{\partial x^k}(\delta^{ik}p+\rho\,v^iv^k).$$
By applying the notation 
$$T^{ik}:=\delta^{ik} p +\rho\,v^i v^k$$
we obtain the representation:
$$\frac{\partial(\rho v^i)}{\partial t}=-\frac{\partial }{\partial x^k}T^{ik}.$$
This result is easily generalized to the relativistic case.